# Problem relating 2 pulleys

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

In the image attached, why is the net force on pulley B, 0? We consider the tension in string 2 twice that of string 1 because we assume the force on B to be 0 and thus no net force on B. But what is the rationale behind such an assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are working with the common intro-physics assumption that the strings and pulleys are massless.
Finite forces on massless objects lead to unphysical accelerations.

If you want to acknowledge that a "frictionless, massless pulley" and a "massless string" are unphysical idealizations, you can instead be explicit that this is an approximation, which gets better when the masses of the pulleys and strings are very much smaller than the masses $M_1$ and $M_2$.  For example, suppose that the mass $M_2$ is several kilograms, while the pulleys have masses of a few grams.  If the rope labeled "2" has a fixed length, then $M_2$ and the pulley $B$ will have the same acceleration.  From $F=ma$, we get

\begin{align}
a_2 &= a_B
\\\\
\frac{F_2}{M_2} &= \frac{F_B}{m_B}
\\
\\
\frac{m_B}{M_2} &= \frac{F_B}{F_2}
\end{align}

For a mass ratio of kilograms versus grams, a factor of a thousand, this says that the ratio of the net forces is *also* a factor of a thousand.  So pretending that the smaller force is exactly zero will introduce an error in the third or fourth significant figure of the larger force.

Comment: So can we come to a generalization that the net force on any massless pulley is 0 in any kind of free body diagram like independent of the case? I may be wrong but as a novice person in Physics I am asking this.

Comment: I would phrase that more carefully, but that is my inner mathematician being pedantic. The introductory problem you've asked about here is about two masses and two tensions. If you make the problem about the two major masses, the masses of the string, of pulley A, and of pulley B, it is no longer a novice problem. There are other nerds-in-the-weeds details that are important with massive pulleys, like their moments of inertia — consider that unrolling a yo-yo takes place at a different pace than dropping the yo-yo. If the mass is negligible, then so are all of these complications.